# How does the Rails router Journey work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, journey

Looking at the [Readme](https://github.com/rails/journey) of the Journey Router (which is the Rails 4.0 router), it is rather empty. I was wondering how the router works conceptually, and if this 'abstract' grammer is catching the idea, of the router as mini-programming-language:

```
ROUTE := GET|POST|PUT|DELETE   path
path := (static_path) | (dynamic_path)
```

So, how does the Rails 4.0 Router work?

Comment: interestingly the synopsis says `Too complex right now. :(`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to understand Rails routing, the best place to start is [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) in the edge guide.

After that, you'll have more luck looking at `ActionDispatch::Routing`'s [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing.html).

*Note: The following relates to Journey v1.0.4, which was the latest at time of writing.*

Journey itself is the Rails routing engine [introduced](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_2_release_notes.html#faster-development-mode-routing) in Rails 3.2. In the release notes, it is described with a single statement: "Route recognition also got a bunch faster thanks to the new [Journey](https://github.com/rails/journey) engine." That's not a lot of info specifically about Journey, of course, but Rails doesn't describe every implementation detail; that would take forever! :) Journey's [gemspec](https://github.com/rails/journey/blob/v1.0.4/journey.gemspec) also describes itself with the statement: "Journey is a router.  It routes requests."

You could look at the [api docs](http://rubydoc.info/gems/journey/1.0.4/frames), but in v1.0.4, it has extremely sparse documentation (Journey::Router::Utils.normalize_path(path) is [documented](http://rubydoc.info/gems/journey/1.0.4/Journey/Router/Utils)) other than the [code itself](https://github.com/rails/journey) and maybe its [open](https://github.com/rails/journey/issues?page=1&state=open) and [closed](https://github.com/rails/journey/issues?page=1&state=closed) issues. You could take a look at the other S.O. posts with tag [journey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/journey).

Some of the code is somewhat self-descriptive just via method names, etc. like in [Journey::Routes](https://github.com/rails/journey/blob/v1.0.4/lib/journey/routes.rb). Journey's [tests](https://github.com/rails/journey/tree/v1.0.4/test) are also a great way to see how it works.

Some notes on the code itself:

- It [monkey-patches Hash](https://github.com/rails/journey/blob/v1.0.4/lib/journey/core-ext/hash.rb) in pre-1.9 versions of Ruby to add a keep_if method.
- "gtg" stands for "generalized transition graph" (see [here](https://github.com/rails/journey/blob/v1.0.4/lib/journey/nfa/transition_table.rb#L48))
- Funniest code is [here](https://github.com/rails/journey/blob/v1.0.4/lib/journey/path/pattern.rb#L22) (Easter egg: `rails c` then `Journey::Path::Pattern.new(9)`)

Journey's [visualizer](https://github.com/rails/journey/blob/v1.0.4/lib/journey/visualizer/index.html.erb) might be interesting to play around with, also (note [visualizer](https://github.com/rails/journey/blob/v1.0.4/lib/journey/gtg/transition_table.rb#L73) method in Journey::GTG::TransitionTable). Sample visualization [here](https://github.com/tenderlove/fsmjs/pull/3), and online demo [here](http://tenderlove.github.io/fsmjs/) for now.

Comment: Thanks, Gary, that last part of your answer was exactly what I was looking for.